# Importing Keras inside of Django causes it to crash

Tags: python, django, theano, keras

I've created a RESTful API for a computer vision app I've made.

It works fine using the existing SVM and previously NOLearn Neural Network.

However, I've trained a new CNN using Keras (Theano backend) and whenever I import Keras inside one of my py modules, it crashes.

```
import keras
```

I also tried importing it into the views.py file and it also crashes.

This is weird and it seems directly related to something with Django. Running python on the machine and doing import keras reveals no issue at all.

What's going on here?

Comment: It is reproducible by running any basic Django project and then importing a full and completely installed Keras

Comment: Also, import theano causes this to crash as well

Comment: The traceback errors:

Answer (score 2):

I came into this error when I call model_load function from  django web backend.
we must create a Session when we use tensorflow in the websever backend!
I fix this by add:

import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session():

```
 //my code to call the Keras unit
```

this may help you.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/client/session_management

Comment: I had to import the keras backend  "from keras import backend as k" and then call "clear_session()" method through that. It was then that I could successfully run the keras model inside Django and load the model many times. this link may help: https://keras.io/backend/