# Import Keras in Django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras

this question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575392/importing-keras-inside-of-django-causes-it-to-crash) but the solution didn't help me. I decided to open a new thread because the topic was to old and the proposed solutions did not work.

So what's the problem:

when i try to import keras, django stop working. When i restart apache in the logs i can see:

```
2020-11-11 10:01:07.783351: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-11-11 10:01:07.783383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

and this is fine. But if i try to access any of my pages they just don't load. Nothing more happen in the log, any error or something.

What am i doing wrong?

My goal is to use a trained model for sentiment analysis.
I'm working on a remote virtual machine with ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6, django 3.1.2, Keras 2.4.3, tensorflow 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried these? Albeit pretty old, there are multiple different solutions that seemed to work for others.

https://serverfault.com/questions/844761/wsgi-truncated-or-oversized-response-headers-received-from-daemon-process

Comment: Thanks, adding `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to apache config file and finally work.

Comment: Super happy to hear that ! :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall TensorFlow and see what happens

Comment: It give me this error 
`ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via pip install tensorflow`

Comment: Hmm, the thing is I'm currently also importing Keras in Django and it works, the only thing that is different is tensorflow==2.2 and Python 3.7.2. Try installing a higher version of python since Keras 2.4.3 requires Python 3.6+.

Comment: Didn't work. In the log there is this line `[Wed Nov 11 14:22:53.717872 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 11996:tid 139696462083840] [client] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'myappssl': /var/www/django/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py` printed just after the tensorflow logs that i posted in the question... what is it?